# Get from related tables with query builder

Tags: laravel, query-builder

Tables: questions (id, question), answers (id, question_id, answer)

One Question has many Answers

How can i get data from one table(e.g questions) and all its related data from another table(answers) using laravel query builder only.

```
DB::table('questions')
                ->rightJoin('answers','questions.id', '=', 'answers.question_id')
                ->groupBy('questions.id')
                ->select('questions.question','answers.answer', 'questions.id', 'answers.question_id')
                ->get();
```

This is what i have so far but it does nt seem to give exactly the way i want the data to be structured.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tables: questions (id, question), answers (id, question_id, answer)

```
$query = DB::table('questions')
             ->join('answers', 'questions.id', '=', 'answers.question_id')
             ->select('questions.question','answers.answer', 'questions.id', 'answers.question_id')
             ->get();
```

Run this and if it still doesn't work, give us a `toSql()` of the query builder's SQL.

You have to be more specific on the way you want the data structured.  It may require more manipulation in PHP if it's more complicated.

Comment: The code you provided just return 1 answer for every question. but it suppose to give multiple answers for every question

Comment: That's not a problem with Laravel or query builder, but a problem with the way you structured your data in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

So in your Question Class you have to add this

```
public function answers(){
      return $this->hasMany('Answer');
}
```

And after if you want the answers of your questions, you can do something like this in your blade view

```
@foreach($questions as $question)
    @foreach($question->answers as $answer)
       <td>{{ $question->question }}</td>
       <td>{{ $answer->answer }}</td>
       <td>{{ $answer->id }}</td>
       <td>{{ $question->id }}</td>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

EDIT: So you're not using eloquent.. just one question, why in your select you get twice the same column? 'questions.id' and 'answers.question_id' will be the same. if you change questions.id by answers.id

```
DB::table('questions')
                ->rightJoin('answers','questions.id', '=', 'answers.question_id')
                ->groupBy('questions.id')
                ->select('questions.question','answers.answer', 'answers.id', 'answers.question_id')
                ->get();
```

Comment: He's not using Eloquent.